# How to parse this json in JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have label in html with Id employeename and I want to set above message employee name is must to html label with Id employeename  how to do it using JavaScript or jquery

```
{"fieldErrors":[{"field":"employeename","message":"NotEmpty.employee.employeename"}]}
The above json I am getting from Ajax respons as 
error:(status,jhxr,errorthrown)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to do that :

```
var str =  '{"fieldErrors":[{"field":"employeename","message":"NotEmpty.employee.employeename"}]}';
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(str);
```

Once it is parsed, You can refer to the keys as an object, like , if you want the "field" inside the object , just say,

```
var field = parsedJson.fieldErrors[0].field;
```

Similarly, for any field inside it.

Comment: its should be var str :)

Comment: It will then return it as an object. to get e.g. the message variable, do it easily with `parsedJson.fieldErrors[0].message`

Comment: @Deep Changed it. But `string` is also fine. Javascript is case-sensitive :). But, Just changed it to avoid confusion.